# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'gaming-peripherals'

Tags: django

I'm building an e-commerce (like) project. While running the program, from Homepage, if we select a product I got hit by this error, instead of showing that product details. Now I can't figure out how to fix this please help me to fix it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e2On.jpg)

Here's my Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    desc=models.TextField(blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='category',blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('name',)
        verbose_name='category'
        verbose_name_plural='categories'

    # for menu linking (url)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse("ecommerce_app:products_by_category",args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)


class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    stock=models.IntegerField()
    available=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    # for url

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse("ecommerce_app:ProdCatDetails",args=[self.category.slug,self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

Her's my Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .  import views
app_name='ecommerce_app'

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.allProdCat,name='allProdCat'),
    # for special urls for Category
    path('<slug:c_slug>/',views.allProdCat,name='products_by_category'),
    # for special urls for Product Details
    path('<slug:c_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/',views.ProdCatDetails,name='ProdCatDetails'),
]
```

Here's my Views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Category,Product
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")


def allProdCat(request,c_slug=None):
    c_page=None
    products=None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=c_slug)
        products=Product.objects.all().filter(category=c_page,available=True)
    else:
        products=Product.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    return render(request,'category.html',{'category':c_page,'products':products})

# For product details

def ProdCatDetails(request,c_slug,product_slug):
    try:
        product=Product.objects.get(category__product=c_slug,slug=product_slug)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return render(request,'product.htmal',{'product':product})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you filter with:

```
product = Product.objects.get(category=c_slug, slug=product_slug)
```

You will filter on the field the `product` `ForeignKey` is referring to. Since that is not specified, this is the *primary key*, and thus an `AutoField`.

You can filter with:

```
#                      filter on the slug ↓
product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=c_slug, slug=product_slug)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants `category__slug` as `category__product` points to the `Product` model itself and `category__product__slug` would then be as good as saying `slug` in a roundabout manner.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: ah yes, I did not really look into the modeling. Thanks! updated